# how to create cron job using php on linux hosting

Tags: php

i trying to create cron using php i tried lot of example on my hosting i dont have cpanel or cli. i tried lot of code. i am new in php. i tried this example

0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php path/of/php/file

or

```
<?/** suppose we have 1 hour and 1 minute inteval 01:01 */

$interval_source = "01:01";
$time_now = strtotime( "now" ) / 60;
$interval = substr($interval_source,0,2) * 60 + substr($interval_source,3,2);


if( $time_now % $interval == 0){
/** do cronjob */
}
```

i dont know where i run this code file pls help me

Comment: You need access to either cPanel or cli (with rights to edit cron jobs) to set up cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `crontab` of linux.

`sudo crontab -e`

Run your cron jobs as

```
/5 * * * *  /path/to/php /var/www/html/yourCodeFile.php
```

This job runs after every 5 minutes.

`yourCodeFile.php` must have the logic of whatever you want to get done.

For more details kindly read this one:
[How to create cron job using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)